# creating a Boolean flag for onclick method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, class, oop, object

I am having some OOP issues that are probably pretty simple. I have a class that renders some html. However it has an onClick that calls a function that sets a flag inside the class if the image is clicked. Now here is the issue, when I render this class object and click the button from a separate js file, it stays false. I want it to permanently change the flag to true when clicked. here is the class...

```
class Settings extends React.Component {

    handleClick() {
        this.flag = true;
        console.log(this.flag)
      }
  
    render(){
        return(
            <img src="./img/leaf.png" alt="" onClick={() => this.handleClick()}/>
        );   
    }

}
```

and here is the code that calls it from a separate file...

```
const settingsObj = new Settings();
console.log(settingsObj.flag);
```

I want the flag to be false until the button is clecked and then it permamently changes to true. But it only goes true until my page rerenders as new data comes in and it resets to false. I have tried constructors and a few other techniques with no success.

Comment: Use local storage to save data otherwise it will be false on every refresh                                                                       
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: If you want something to be permanent you need to store something on the server or in localstorage. If you want something to just be for the current session you might want to look into Context

Comment: Why are you explicitly calling `const settingsObj = new Settings();` ? Normally Components are added one inside another in React, and that's the way to assure states are remaining the same until you change their value. If you have Component App, consider to add Settings Component inside of render function of App, a bit like `render() { return (<Settings />); }` . And React will do the correct OOP call for you

Comment: I definitely want the Latter, context. Any links or solutions though?

Comment: KeitelDOG can you show example? I am doing exactly this if I remove the object but it doesn't hold.

Comment: @epascarello - but the OP's requirement seems to be localized to this component - not global. So Context doesn't seem to make sense.

Comment: Unless, of-course, this is a _global_ settings class - which is exactly what Context is for :-)

Comment: I am writing up an example using Context, but give me a few minutes!

Comment: @JustinOberle - is your longer term intent to create a _global settings_ capability?

Comment: If so, then @epascarello is correct - Context is the tool to use.

Comment: I am basically trying to conditionally render different stuff if the flag is true, or in other word, if the user clicks the image. I might be way overcomplicating this. The problem is the flag resets to false and the original render occurs.

Comment: I think I can resolve this by using conditional rendering from the main page. I will play around and post code in a bit for the solution but this is basically a conditional rendering question. Sorry I should have clarified better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this kind of interactions, I highly recommend you to use **[Redux](https://react-redux.js.org/)**

Another think I'm sure you will benefit from, is switching to **hooks** and **function components**: less boilerplate and much flexible code.

Back to the goal, using Redux your code would look similar to this:

```js
const Settings = (props) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const flag = useSelector(state => state.yourStoreObj.flag);
      
  handleClick() {
    dispatch(yourCustomAction("UPDATE_FLAG", true));
  }
  
  return(
        <img src="./img/leaf.png" alt="" onClick={() => handleClick()}/>
    );  
}
```

**Explanation**:

First of all, spend 15 mins and get used to React Redux. Here's a [good practical article](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/react-redux-hooks-useselector-and-usedispatch-f7d8c7f75cdd) to start with. If you're not familiar with hooks, [start learning them](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) as that will change a lot, while you don't need to change a single line of what you've done so far.

We suppose there's a property in the store that is the "flag" property of that specific element. In this way, the **property can be read by the component** itself with the **useSelector()** operator, or can be read anywhere in your application with the same methodology from any other component.

In the same way, you can **change the value by dispatching a change** (see dispatch() function) and in the same way, you can do that from any other components.

So, let's say you want to change that property when a click occurs on a completely different component, this is how the other component may looks like

```js
const OtherCoolComp = (props) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  
  handleClick() {
    dispatch(yourCustomAction("UPDATE_FLAG", true));
  }
  
  return(
        <button onClick={() => handleClick()}>
          Click me!
        </button>
    );  
}
```

So you're dispatching the same action, setting it to the value you prefer, from a component that doesn't know who is displaying that value.

Comment: This is great. I resolved with simplifying my code and using functions with hooks. I will look into redux too. Thanks!

Comment: It's worth noting that behind the scenes Redux uses the React Context API.  I love Redux.  I wouldn't recommend it if the global state is a single boolean value, but it's great when there is a large and complex global state.

Comment: @LindaPaiste you are right but a React App with just a boolean value is something I've never seen. Definitively for just a boolean value Redux it's a big structure, but once you've set it up, you can use for so many other things. That said, I have highly appreciated your answer too, really complete and detailed!

Answer (score 2):

Normal OOP design principles don't always apply directly to React components.  Components don't usually have instance properties, they mostly just have `props` and `state` (there are a few exceptions where you do use an instance property, like `Animation` objects in react-native, but these are rare).

You're kind of mixing the two things in a way that doesn't quite make sense here.  `Settings` is a React component that renders an image, but it's also an object which you instantiate by calling `new Settings()`.  If there are other components which depend on the value of `flag`, you might want to separate the accessing and storing of the flag from the render component, passing a value and a callback to the renderer.

```
const Settings = ({setFlag}) => {
      return(
          <img src="./img/leaf.png" alt="" onClick={() => setFlag(true)}/>
      );
}
```

You've suggested that you like the [Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) as a solution for making the `flag` value globally available.  There are a few ways to set this up, but here's one.

Outside of any component, we create a `FlagContext` object that has two properties: a `boolean` value `flag` and callback function `setFlag`.  We need to give it a default fallback value, which is hopefully never used, so our default callback just logs a warning and does nothing.

```
const FlagContext = createContext<FlagContextState>({
  flag: false,
  setFlag: () => console.warn("attempted to use FlagContext outside of a valid provider")
});
```

This `FlagContext` object gives up `Provider` and `Consumer` components, but it's up to us to give a `value` to the `FlagContext.Provider`.  So we'll create a custom component that handles that part.  Our custom `FlagProvider` uses a local state to create and pass down the value.  I've used a function component, but you could use a class component as well.

```
const FlagProvider = ({children}) => {
  const [flag, setFlag] = useState(false);

  return (
    <FlagContext.Provider value={{
      flag,
      setFlag
    }}>
      {children}
    </FlagContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

We want to put **the entire App** inside of the `FlagProvider` so that the whole app has the potential to access `flag` and `setFlag`, and the whole app gets the same `flag` value.

When you want to use the value from the context in a component, you use either the `useContext` hook or the `Consumer` component.  Either way, I like to creating an aliased name and export that rather than exporting the `FlagContext` object directly.

```
export const FlagConsumer = FlagContext.Consumer;

export const useFlagContext = () => useContext(FlagContext);
```

With the `Consumer`, the child of the consumer is a function that takes the value of the context, which in out case is an object with properties `flag` and `setFlag`, and returns some JSX.

This is usually a function you define inline:

```
const SomePage = () => {
  return (
    <FlagConsumer>
      {({flag, setFlag}) => (<div>Flag Value is {flag.toString()}</div>)}
    </FlagConsumer>
  )
}
```

But it can also be a function component. Note that when using a function component as the child, you must pass the component itself (`{Settings}`) rather than an executed version of it (`<Settings />`).

```
const Settings = ({ setFlag }) => {
  return <img src="./img/leaf.png" alt="" onClick={() => setFlag(true)} />;
};

const SomePage = () => {
  return <FlagConsumer>{Settings}</FlagConsumer>;
};
```

The preferred method nowadays is with hooks. We call `useFlagContext()` inside the body of the function component and it returns our context object.

```
const SomePage = () => {
  const {flag, setFlag} = useFlagContext();

  return <Settings setFlag={setFlag}/>
};
```

Both the consumer and the hook only work if they are inside of a flag context provider, so that's why we put it around the whole app!

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <FlagProvider>
      <SomePage />
    </FlagProvider>
  );
};
```

Complete example on [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-64732559-iiifg?file=/src/App.js)